Apex export to exel change cell height
How can i change the height of the exported cells in oracle apex, the build in export function for exel. I am using a Interactive grid report with the build in export function.
We have very big reports and the cell height is also differrent from row to row, ofcurse the useres can modify the cellheight with exel, but is there also a sulution direct in apex?
Apex version 23.2

Pretty sure this is not possible
